Hydration issues with NextJS and i18next
I am working on a small project which is in an nx monorepo that contains three packages,

Components
Services
App

The app is written in nextjs (13.5.6) and I added next-i18next (15.2.0) & i18next (23.10.1) & react-i18next (14.1.0) in the main repo while I added these configs in the App package to support translations.
--next.config.js
//@ts-check

// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires
const { composePlugins, withNx } = require('@nx/next');

/**
 * @type {import('@nx/next/plugins/with-nx').WithNxOptions}
 **/
const baseNextConfig = {
  nx: {
    // Set this to true if you would like to use SVGR
    // See: https://github.com/gregberge/svgr
    svgr: false,
  },
  compiler: {
    // For other options, see https://styled-components.com/docs/tooling#babel-plugin
    styledComponents: true,
  },
};

const { i18n } = require('./next-i18next.config.js');

const plugins = [
  // Add more Next.js plugins to this list if needed.
  withNx,
  (/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */ config) => {
    // Merge all configurations except for output
    const { output, ...restConfig } = config;
    const mergedConfig = { ...restConfig, i18n };
    return mergedConfig;
  },
];

// Base Next.js configuration object
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  // Your Next.js configuration options
  output: 'export', // For example, you can set output here
};

// Merge the base Next.js config with the provided nextConfig
const mergedNextConfig = { ...baseNextConfig, ...nextConfig };

// Apply plugins
module.exports = composePlugins(...plugins)(mergedNextConfig);

--And here is my next-i18next.config.js
module.exports = {
debug: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development',
i18n: {
  defaultLocale: 'en',
  locales: ['en', 'pt'],
    },
  };

And the structure of the app pages that it contains two pages, index.tsx & interview.tsx and in the interview.tsx I am loading the translations using getStaticProps as following
export async function getStaticProps({ locale }: Locale) {
  return {
    props: {
      ...(await serverSideTranslations(locale,
        // This is unnecessary as 'common' is fetched by default but I leave 
        // it here as a reference in case we need to add more sections/files 
        // inside the JSON so the approach is clear
        [
          'common',
        ])),
    },
  }
}

and then I destruct the method "t" from the hook "useTranslation" but whenever I load the page, I get such errors in the console while the translations show up properly in the page

Uncaught Error: There was an error while hydrating. Because the error happened outside of a Suspense boundary, the entire root will switch to client rendering.
Uncaught Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.
Uncaught Error: Text content does not match server-rendered HTML.

I am using MUI to render the components and the translation files are inside public/locales/*/[locale].json
Is there anything I can do to fix this issue? It only happens when I use getStaticProps to load the translations properly.
Thanks in advance.
